# Does someone know why concat es working for certain values?

Tags: mysql

can someone telling me why is CONCAT function not working for hour 22 and 23 please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKDC4.png)

```html
   SELECT CODIGO
, ZONA
, FECHA_INICIO
, FECHA_TERMINO
, hour(FECHA_INICIO) AS HOUR
, Case when minute(fecha_inicio) < 15 THEN 1 
            when minute(fecha_inicio) < 30 THEN 2
            when minute(fecha_inicio) < 45 THEN 3
            when minute(fecha_inicio) < 60 THEN 4 END AS QUARTER
, CONCAT((hour(FECHA_INICIO)), 
"-" , 
(Case when minute(fecha_inicio) < 15 THEN 1 
            when minute(fecha_inicio) < 30 THEN 2
            when minute(fecha_inicio) < 45 THEN 3
            when minute(fecha_inicio) < 60 THEN 4 END)) AS HQ
, sum(case when ESTADO = 'terminada' then 1 else 0 end) as complete

from 
( SELECT 
CASE WHEN extract(hour from convert_tz(FECHA_TERMINO,@@session.time_zone,'America/Mexico_city'))<12 
    THEN date(convert_tz(FECHA_TERMINO,@@session.time_zone,'America/Mexico_city')) 
    ELSE Date_add(date(convert_tz(FECHA_TERMINO,@@session.time_zone,'America/Mexico_city')), interval 1 day) 
END AS close_date
, CODIGO
, ZONA
, DATE_SUB(FECHA_INICIO, INTERVAL 5 HOUR) AS FECHA_INICIO
, DATE_SUB(FECHA_TERMINO, INTERVAL 5 HOUR) AS FECHA_TERMINO
, ESTADO
from TASK_MANAGER_
where ( ESTADO = 'liberada' or ESTADO = 'terminada')
and SITIO = '{{Bodega}}'
and ZONA NOT IN ('ENTREGA CERTIFICADA', 'ZONA5')
) as aux_tab
where close_date in ('{{ Fecha }}')
Group by CODIGO
ORDER BY FECHA_INICIO
```

Comment: ```Case when minute(fecha_inicio) < 15 THEN 1 when minute(fecha_inicio) < 30 THEN 2 when minute(fecha_inicio) < 45 THEN 3 when minute(fecha_inicio) < 60 THEN 4 END``` can be replaced with simple ```1 + (minute(fecha_inicio) DIV 15)```.

Comment: *why is CONCAT function not working for hour 22 and 23* Does `hour(FECHA_INICIO) AS HOUR` in the output list shows the values whereas the result of `CONCAT(..)` is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

> Check whether you are limiting the string to 3 digits in your code.

It is working fine for me.

```
SET @fecha_inicio = STR_TO_DATE('2017-06-27T23:59:00.123','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f');

select CONCAT((hour(@fecha_inicio)), 
"-" , 
(Case when minute(@fecha_inicio) < 15 THEN 1 
            when minute(@fecha_inicio) < 30 THEN 2
            when minute(@fecha_inicio) < 45 THEN 3
            when minute(@fecha_inicio) < 60 THEN 4 END)) AS HQ ;
```